# Bottom share menu iOS [Obj-c]

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to create bottom share menu in my application like this one screen[image]
 it should simple view with buttons and collection view or external framework?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please look at [ask]. Show your own efforts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code:

```
NSArray * activityItems = @[@"",[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]];
NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
NSArray * excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Objective C**

```
- (IBAction)shareText:(id)sender {
  // create a message
  NSString *theMessage = @"Some text we're sharing with an activity controller";
  NSArray *items = @[theMessage];

 // build an activity view controller
  UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController  alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

 // and present it
  [self presentActivityController:controller];
}
- (void)presentActivityController:(UIActivityViewController *)controller {
 // for iPad: make the presentation a Popover
   controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
   [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

   UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [controller popoverPresentationController];
   popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
   popController.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;

 // access the completion handler
   controller.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType,
                                      BOOL completed,
                                      NSArray *returnedItems,
                                      NSError *error){
// react to the completion
if (completed) {

    // user shared an item
    NSLog(@"We used activity type%@", activityType);

} else {

    // user cancelled
    NSLog(@"We didn't want to share anything after all.");
}

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"An Error occured: %@, %@", error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason);
}
};
}
```

**Swift**

```
let shareText = "Hello, world!"

if let image = UIImage(named: "myImage") {
   let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, image], applicationActivities: [])
   presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To share a UIImage on iPhone for example, we’ll do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)shareImageDefault:(id)sender { // grab an item we want to share 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"three"]; 
NSArray *items = @[image]; // build an activity view controller        
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil]; // and present it 
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{ // executes after the user selects something }]; }
```